# My @keyframes image is growing outside of my div?

Tags: css

My image that is using @keyframes scales beyond my div="image-zoom". It zooms correctly but as it zooms within the div it goes outside and the horizontal slider increases.

HTML:

```
<section id="intro-section">
    <div id="image-zoom">
        <h1>WELCOME</h1>
    </div> <!-- /.container -->
</section>
```

CSS:

```
#intro-section {
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
}

#image-zoom {
    background-image: url(/img/fairy-bg.jpg);
    background-size:100%;
    position:relative;
    top:237;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:400px;
    animation: zoom 30s infinite;
    padding: 0;
}

@keyframes zoom {
    0% { transform:scale(1,1); }
    50% { transform:scale(1.2,1.2); }
    100% { transform:scale(1,1); }
}
```

I know it's simple but I can't see where the mistake is.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an `overflow: hidden` to the containing `<div>`

Answer (score 0):

This is where the issue lies:

```
transform:scale(1.2,1.2)
```

The scale is more than the container size. (1 = container size)